# Throw compiler errors

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-construction

It is possible to throw error at runtime with `throw`.

```
throw new Error( "Error message!" );
```

Is it possible to throw errors or warnings at compile time from AS3 code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not, unless you could somehow modify the compiler or write your own.

You can't write code to throw a compile-time error, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: It can make sense in certain cases. For example I'm using compiler conditionals depending on the compile target (desktop/mobile). The problem is I have to manually change the constants in my IDE depending on which target I compile. If I could throw a compiler error I could know when I forgot to change the constant.

Comment: @Pier That information seems very important and something you should add to your question.

Comment: I think my question is quite clear... If my question had been "how to avoid forgetting to manually change compiler constants" then you'd have a point.

Comment: @Pier To me your question is asking whether you can `throw` a compile-time error (i.e. via ActionScript).

Comment: Exactly... so my problem with the compiler constants are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It would be helpful to throw a compiler error in the instance of creating a Singleton Class. Since you can't declare the constructor as private, you have to raise an error on an instantiation attempt. It would be nice to do that before you're program has been running for half an hour.